# Воспроизведение mp3 в Python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, модуль для воспроизведения mp3-шных файлов, ничего в гугле не найду.

Answer (score 1):

Например, [The Snack Sound Toolkit](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/)

```
sound = Sound() 
sound.read('sound.mp3') 
sound.play()
```

Comment: from Tkinter import*
sn=Sound()
sn.read('F:\files\1te.mp3') 
sn.play()

ругается:
NameError: name 'Sound' is not defined

Comment: Делайте как в документации:

    import tkSnack
    tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
    # Now you can use tkSnack commands and objects
    sn=tkSnack.Sound()
    sn.read('F:\files\1te.mp3') 
    sn.play()

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть [pygame](http://pygame.org/).  Представляет собой набор библиотек и предназначен для написания компьютерных игр и мультимедиа-приложений.

Answer (score 1):

Для какой платформы надо? Под windows у меня работает только через ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *
winmm = windll.winmm
winmm.mciSendStringA('Open "test.mp3" Type MPEGVideo Alias theMP3',0,0,0)
winmm.mciSendStringA('Play theMP3 Wait',0,0,0)
```

Подробности [Play MP3 Files with Python on Windows](http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/play-mp3-files-with-python-on-windows.html).
Стандартных, надежно работающих кроссплатформенных модулей, тем более для mp3 вроде нет. Раньше пробовал pygame - вроде в скрипте что-то происходит, а звука нет. Был еще модуль PyMedia, он нормально работал, но кажется его развитие остановилось на python-2.5.